# How to display scroll to top button in a page that only have vertical scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to only display the scroll to top/bottom button in the page that have vertical scroll bar. However , the button does not appear when the page contain vertical scroll bar. Is there any idea how to implement this feature ?

`ScrollToTopBottom.vue`

```
<template>
      <div v-if= "hasVerticalScroll" v-scroll="onScroll" >
        <v-btn v-if = "!isVisible"
            fab fixed bottom right color="primary" @click="toBottom">
            <v-icon>mdi-arrow-down-bold-box-outline</v-icon>
        </v-btn>

        <v-btn v-else
            fab fixed bottom right color="primary" @click="toTop">
            <v-icon>mdi-arrow-up-bold-box-outline</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </div>
</template>

<script>

export default{
    data () {
        return {
        isVisible: false,
        position: 0,

    }
  },
   methods: {
    onScroll () {
      this.isVisible = window.scrollY > 500
    },
    toTop () {
      this.position = window.scrollY
      window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      })
    },
    toBottom(){
      let pos = this.position > 0 ? this.position : document.body.scrollHeight
      window.scrollTo({
        top: pos,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      })
    },
  },
  computed: {
      hasVerticalScroll(){
        console.log('offsetHeight',document.body.offsetHeight);
        console.log('windowinner',window.innerHeight);
        return document.body.offsetHeight > window.innerHeight;
      }
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `hasVerticalScroll` to method in parent component ad listen to scroll event:

```js
Vue.component('scrollToTopButton', {
  template: `
    <div v-scroll="onScroll" >
      <v-btn v-if="!isVisible" fab fixed bottom right color="primary" @click="toBottom">
        <v-icon>mdi-arrow-down-bold-box-outline</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn v-else fab fixed bottom right color="primary" @click="toTop">
        <v-icon>mdi-arrow-up-bold-box-outline</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </div>
  `,
  data () {
    return {
      isVisible: false,
      position: 0
    }
  },
   methods: {
    onScroll() {
      this.isVisible = window.scrollY > 50
    },
    toTop() {
      this.position = window.scrollY
      window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      })
    },
    toBottom(){
      let pos = this.position > 0 ? this.position : document.body.scrollHeight
      window.scrollTo({
        top: pos,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      })
    },
  },

})
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      hasScroll: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    hasVerticalScroll() {
      this.hasScroll = document.body.offsetHeight > window.innerHeight; 
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="demo" >
  <v-app v-scroll="hasVerticalScroll">
    <v-main>
      <v-container >
        <div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div>
        <div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div><div>xxx</div>
        <scroll-to-top-button v-if="hasScroll" ></scroll-to-top-button>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: if i click the button to top , the button will be appearing in pages that has no vertical scrollbar. However if i click the button to bottom , the button wont be appearing in pages that do not have vertical scroll and will be appear in pages that has vertical scrollbar

Comment: sorry mate, I can't reproduce your problem, maybe you can put `hasScroll` in global state and populate it on every page load. Any ways the event fires on scroll so you can try to scroll on pages to see was button still here.

Comment: its alright u helped me alot , its working actually , just that if i clicked the scroll to top button, it would be appearing in all pages including without vertical scrollbar. But if the scroll button is not clicked , everything working as intended which i wanted the button to appear in the page containing vertical bar only

Comment: ahhh , if i use my mouse to scroll back up, the button will be appearing in every page including no vertical scrollbar page. this is weird haha

Comment: check again pls, I updated my answer , set `v-if` on your button component.

Comment: could you help me ? i just posted a new question. the scroll back to bottom will be appearing in every page. however, if its scroll back to top button, it will only be appearing in page that contain vertical bars only. the problem is the scroll back to bottom will appear in every pages. hope u could help me

Comment: in the code snippet  when it's current is scroll to top button icon , the button will not be appearing in page when there's no vertical scroll bar. When it's current is scroll to bottom , it will show up too in page that do not have vertical scrollbar.  how do i fix the scroll to bottom button to not appear in page that do not have vertical scrollbar?

Comment: could u help me @Nikola Pavicevic i really do need your help. I would be appreciate if you could help me again

Comment: @jeff sorry mate, I can't reproduce your problem, don't know how to solve it :(

Comment: could you go through this question that i posted yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72518604/any-idea-to-how-to-hide-scroll-to-bottom-button ? @Nikola Pavicevic . sorry to trouble because i have been stuck for days solving this problem but it's fine if really cant solve it

Comment: yes I saw that but like I said I can not reproduce the problem, too little context , in order to solve your issue I will need to recreate whole your app

Comment: ah its alright. So any suggestion you can give me for now ? would it be okay to show the scroll to top and bottom in all pages ?

Comment: it should work like I answered you, maybe some css is messing with it...

Comment: :(( i will try go and figure out again, i hope i can find the problem in apps

Comment: its working as intended, i try put the function from `default.vue` to other pages that contains vertical scrollbar and do not contain vertical scrollbar. I think my `default.vue` has a problem since its the parent component because I want to put it there so it is accessible in every page